# How to de-duplicate recored in customized object?

Tags: apex, merge

I have 250K disordered and duplicated records in a customized object. After i search salesforce help document, i found that merge() function looks like not support customized object. But, if i use batch for de-duplicate, still can not merge same record, because batch size execute 2000 record pre times. So, i can not find best solution for de-duplicate. Please help me? how to address this problem?

Comment: You need to provide more detailed info about your custom object.

Comment: My custom object has 5 field. People_name, hospital, product, region and suggestion. And record more than 250K. I want to use People_name+hospital merge all duplicate record. Is there some idea to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see that there is an out of the box solution for this. You may need to create your own mechanism.

**On the platform**

To dedupe using APEX and Visualforce you will likely have to split up the process into very small chunks and do it iteratively. Therefore you may use batch apex but still you may end up in a multi pass strategy to dedupe a single record. The basic recipe would be to first loop through all records and than compare a filtered list of dupes (matching the criteria of what you consider a dupe) to the actual record and merge them with plain APEX by copying (or merging) field by field explicitly.

**Dedupe locally**

An other approach to circumvent a long limit-consideration would be to consolidate the data outside salesforce. I would use an ETL tool like Talend https://www.talend.com/ to export the data into something local. What format you choose depends mostly on what is convenient for you. A local MySQL server could work or even Excel should do it. How to proceed also mostly depends on you skills. Could be done in VBA, PHP, or whaterver - (nearly) **without limits**. Then use Talend to get it back into Salesforce.